# OpenNLP Extract Grammar

Tags: java, nlp, grammar, opennlp

I'm currently looking through opennlp source code trying to find/understand the grammar that they use for chunking. This is not one of the easiest tasks. I started looking through the chunkermodel and associated classes but haven't gotten too far..

Has anyone ever searched for this? If so any suggestions or ideas that will put me on path?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the algorithms bundled with Apache OpenNLP are based on machine learning technology, using statistical approach. There is no grammar in the models, but the parameters extracted from training data.

To learn more about the algorithms I recommend Jurafsky & Martin book "Speech and Language Processing", section 6.7.

You could also refer to Ratnaparkhi's dissertation: [Maximun Entropy Models for Natural Language Ambiguity Resolution](http://www.ai.mit.edu/courses/6.891-nlp/READINGS/adwait.pdf)

And for Perceptron HMM, the Michael Collins paper: [Discriminative training methods for hidden Markov models: theory and experiments with perceptron algorithms](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1118694)

If you what you looking for is grammar approach, try the Contraint Grammar formalism. [VISL website](http://beta.visl.sdu.dk/constraint_grammar.html) lists some publications.